Cloud Run user groups are ignored -- only primary group and sudo are taken
Let's say I have this Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt -y update && apt -y install sudo
RUN useradd -G sudo,www-data -s /bin/bash timmy
RUN passwd -d timmy
RUN cat <<EOF > test.sh
id
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/sample-site
sudo touch /var/www/sample-site/index.html
sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www/sample-site
sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www/sample-site
ls -al /var/www
echo "Sample site" > /var/www/sample-site/index.html
cat /var/www/sample-site/index.html
cat /etc/group 
EOF
RUN chmod +x test.sh
USER timmy
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash","-c","./test.sh" ]

and used Docker build and run command
docker build -t test:latest .
docker run -it --name test-sample test:latest 

I got this output
uid=1000(timmy) gid=1000(timmy) groups=1000(timmy),27(sudo),33(www-data)
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root     25 Dec 22 18:39 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     17 Dec 22 18:39 ..
drwxrwx---. 2 root www-data 24 Dec 22 18:39 sample-site
Sample site
root:x:0:
:
sudo:x:27:timmy
www-data:x:33:timmy
timmy:x:1000:

All that good as expected, now when I run this exact image on GCP Cloud Run, I get the following from the log
DEFAULT 2024-12-22T18:40:01.416557Z uid=1000(timmy) gid=1000(timmy) groups=1000(timmy)
DEFAULT 2024-12-22T18:40:01.608104Z total 0
DEFAULT 2024-12-22T18:40:01.608120Z drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 60 Dec 22 18:40 .
DEFAULT 2024-12-22T18:40:01.608126Z drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 60 Dec 22 18:40 ..
DEFAULT 2024-12-22T18:40:01.608132Z drwxrwx--- 2 root www-data 60 Dec 22 18:40 sample-site
DEFAULT 2024-12-22T18:40:01.613976Z ./test.sh: line 7: /var/www/sample-site/index.html: Permission denied
DEFAULT 2024-12-22T18:40:01.614241Z cat: /var/www/sample-site/index.html: Permission denied
root:x:0:
:
sudo:x:27:timmy
www-data:x:33:timmy
timmy:x:1000:

First of all : the --no-new-privileges flag can only reset if you have Cloud SQL Connection setup, even if you don't need it but that the only way I think to reset this flag otherwise I won't be able to run sudo commands.
Second, although the groups are set in /etc/group file in both runs (Docker run and Cloud Run) but Cloud Run seems to "ignore" these groups and stick with the primary group only (not sure why it exempt sudo group)
Any light could be shed on this problem is highly appreciated,
I just want to get the permissions for user timmy to access group allowed files and directories.

Why are you trying to recreate the file structure every time you run the container?  I'd remove the script, and every mention of sudo, and put the setup commands in Dockerfile RUN statements so that they only need to be done once when the image is built.

this is for development environment dockers, these docker images are setup to restructure my dev environment every time I need to, such as (crashes or anything) I agree, for production containers this whole discussion would be different. Now why I am deploying a dev environment on to Cloud Run? that's for testing and exploiting capabilities of Cloud Run (say Experimenting)

I am sharing this might help someone, while trying different options to understand the behaviour, noticed that docker run -u userid:groupid would deliver same results (which is ignoring user original groups), I am now convinced that Cloud Run would override the user:group when running containers, but they don't use it if there is sql-connection attached. (i think it is a bug)

When running your Docker container on Google Cloud Run, there might be differences in the environment that could be causing issues that are not present when running locally. These differences can include user permissions, file system behavior, and how the entrypoint script is executed. This might work.
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Install sudo
RUN apt -y update && apt -y install sudo

# Create user 'timmy' and add to sudo and www-data groups
RUN useradd -G sudo,www-data -s /bin/bash timmy
RUN passwd -d timmy

# Allow 'timmy' to run sudo commands without a password
RUN echo 'timmy ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

# Create the script with necessary sudo commands
RUN bash -c 'cat <<EOF > /test.sh
#!/bin/bash
id
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/sample-site
sudo touch /var/www/sample-site/index.html
sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www/sample-site
sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www/sample-site
ls -al /var/www
echo "Sample site" | sudo tee /var/www/sample-site/index.html
sudo cat /var/www/sample-site/index.html
cat /etc/group
EOF'

# Make the script executable
RUN chmod +x /test.sh

# Switch to user 'timmy'
USER timmy

# Set the entrypoint to run the script
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/test.sh"]


As expected, I know this won't solve the problem but tried it any way, hopefully get another hint to the problem, I did run the above and got exact results, again, the problem isn't about granting sudo to the user which your solution implies, it is about sudo or groups in general aren't ported to the user at execution time of the docker container, that been said, the code works perfectly on rund docker service on my local development server, that leads to conclude that google version or rund isn't working right!

I see. I don't have a GCP account, otherwise I would have tested the solution for sure. well, I would still try to find something that might work.

I did chmod 777 for the folder as a workaround but not satisfied.
